# IoT Hub publisher via redsocks and proxy drops connection

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I'm using `azure-iot-device-amqp`. I have a proxied connection so I'm using `redsocks` to reroute the connection via the proxy.

However, the proxy server sometimes drops the connection and starts again. But, the IoT hub publisher does not detect this. It keeps sending data and the IoT Hub does not receive anything. Nothing is shown on the IoT Hub subscriber as well.

I dont get the `Message Enqueued` message.

Comment: What's your platform, Linux or Windows?

Comment: Its Ubuntu 16.04. I didnt think it would matter.

Comment: You can check [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/604). It seems still in progress.

Comment: But we're also facing similar issue while using the MQTT package.

Comment: Yes, AMQP and MQTT both have the issue but HTTP works for me.